# Resource URIs not working in Java RESTful web service on tomcat 8 server

Tags: java, rest, maven, tomcat, netbeans

I created a RESTful web service using auto generated entity classes with netbeans. I also used maven. I deployed this in tomcat 8 as localhost. I do see the index page, but I cannot access any endpoints. I initially ran this locally on Glassfish server and it worked fine. 
I tried test resource uri in netbeans but it says,

> Unable to open resource URL : localhost:8080//api/activity

Here is my server.xml file from apache tomcat.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 --><Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener"/>

  <Listener SSLEngine="on" className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener"/>

  <GlobalNamingResources>

    <Resource auth="Container" description="User database that can be updated and saved" factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory" name="UserDatabase" pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"/>
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <Service name="Catalina">


    <Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>

    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"/>

    <Engine defaultHost="localhost" name="Catalina">

      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">

        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">

        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"/>

      <Context antiJARLocking="true" docBase="C:\xxx\yyyy\apache-tomcat-8.0.36\apache-tomcat-8.0.36\wtpwebapps\xxDBWithMaven" path="/VoyateDBWithMaven" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:VoyateDBWithMaven"/></Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Is there anyway I can fix this so the resources can be accessed? It's confusing because the application gets deployed and the index file is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

> Unable to open resource URL : localhost:8080//api/activity

You have two slashes between "localhost:8080" and "api/activity". Remove one in the configuration where you specify the path: `api/activity` instead of `/api/activity`.